# Why is the general solution of the Klein-Gordon equation a distribution?

Tags: field-theory, mathematics, differential-equations, dirac-delta-distributions, klein-gordon-equation

I posted this question on [math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4821543/) but I thought it might also be appropriate to post it here.

Consider the Klein-Gordon equation:
$$(\square + m^2)\phi = (\partial_t^2 - \Delta + m^2)\phi = 0 \tag{1}$$
The solution to this equation is typically obtained by writing $\phi$ as an inverse Fourier transform:
$$\phi(x,t) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} e^{i (k \cdot x)} \hat{\phi}(t,k) d^3k$$
and then substituting this into (1) to get
$$(\partial_t^2 - k^2 + m^2)\hat{\phi} = 0. \tag{2}$$

From here it is often stated that the general solution to (2) must be a distribution, but why is this? Why can we not get a strong/classical solution?

Comment: Who's saying that "the general solution must be a distribution" and in what context? Are you perhaps confusing this with a) the statement that *quantum fields* are operator-valued distributions or b) the notion of *Green's functions*, which are indeed often distributions but are solutions to the equation with the $\delta$-distribution and not 0 on the r.h.s.?

Comment: @ACuriousMind In page 3 of [this link](https://homepages.physik.uni-muenchen.de/~helling/classical_fields.pdf) they state that $\phi$ is a distribution, and also [on physicsforums.com](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-to-derive-general-solution-to-the-klein-gordon-equation.866653/). Perhaps when they say that it is a distribution they mean they found a weak solution to (2)? But this is not what the computations show.

Comment: The pdf you link explicitly mentions it's talking about the Green's function $\phi_g$, not $\phi$, when saying it's a distribution, so this is my case b) - you're just misreading the text. It even says that in general $\phi$ itself will turn out to be a function for nice enough $u$ (and $u=0$ is certainly nice)!

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thank you, is an explicit solution known for $u = 0$?